# ASPNET Boilerpate - How to override/redirect calls to App Service?

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

I have two AppServices, TestAppService and Test2AppService. I want calls to Test to be redirected to Test2, for example:

```
http://localhost:21021/api/services/app/Test/GetAll
```

should give me the results of

```
http://localhost:21021/api/services/app/Test2/GetAll
```

But I cannot edit TestAppService.

For now my workaround is renaming the controller during Module initialization:

```
.ConfigureControllerModel(model =>
    {
        if (model.ControllerName == "Test")
            model.ControllerName = "Test2";
        // Need to rename Test2 or it would be ambiguous
        else if (model.ControllerName == "Test2")
            model.ControllerName = "Test";
    });
```

Is there a better/simpler way to do this? I actually only need to redirect one method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to do it using a HttpGet attribute with Order = -1:

```
[HttpGet("api/services/app/Test/GetAll", Order = -1)]
public async override Task<List<Data>> GetAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using AspNetCore.

You could disable TestAppService with `[RemoteService(false)]`, see https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/AspNet-Core#application-services-as-controllers

Follow by adding route attribute like `[Route("api/test/[action]")]` to your Test2AppService